# can vxworks task names have spaces or special characters?

Tags: multithreading, scheduled-tasks, vxworks

What are the legal characters for a vxworks task name?

void startTask( void )
{
   char taskname[ 100 ] = "foo";

taskSpawn( taskname,  ... )
}

And, does taskSpawn copy taskname?  Because obvsiously taskname is function scope only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task Name can be any string, but VxWorks will append a "t" to the front and limit it to 10 characters. I.E. if you task name is "My New Task" it will appear as "tMy New Ta".
And to directly answer your question, yes it will copy the name, so you can dynamically create task names that don't need to reside in global memory.